# Image won't show up in my web page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to display an image on my html page but it won't work on Explorer or Microsoft Edge. However, it works on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. 
This is my html:

```
<img src="../Recursos/logoam.jpg" width="600" height="130" style="float:left">
```

My image is in another folder than my html page.

Comment: Look for errors in the browser console. The path probably isn't correct, and the console should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Can you post your directory structure so that we can get an idea of how you have the directories set out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be with your src attribute.".." at the starting of a path is applied when you want to access a folder which is located one level up from your current position.for eg: there is a folder named "abc", inside it there are two subfolders: "scripts" and "images".Now suppose there is a file in "scripts" folder that wants to access an image which is located in "images" folder,then you have to provide ".." at the start of the path to move from level "scripts" to level "abc". The rest of the path starts from there.If your Recursos folder is at the same level as your main .html file,then you dont need to provide ".." at the start.
For more details look at the given below link:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for problems of this type is path errors ie, you are providing wrong paths for the image.
../ in the path means it begins the search from one level above the present directory.
../../ in path means it begins searching from two level above the present directory.
./ in path means it begins searching from the current directory.

So, you have to use the path properly to load the image. If the Recursos directory is the sibling of the directory containing the html file, then it should work.
If not, use the above notation properly to load the image. In case of doubt or confusion, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the console for any path related error for the image. Code looks fine.

Answer (score -3):

Your TAG is missing the BACKSLASH

```
<img src="../Recursos/logoam.jpg" width="600" height="130" style="float:left" />
```